# QR code doesnt read " + " symbol

Tags: php, encryption, qr-code

While making a QR code for my encrypted link I noticed that the " + " sign wasn't included in the QR code.

Sample link: `http://localhost/cp//form?ASLV2N0+YmkHz6ELPjgEoqbA7qYQ69eoTReV9jSwEviaqJi8j54kQmpbaVK58LlFZmjhKG+X3uyPpZ6fC0/H2A==`

Is there anyway to remove the + symbol in my encryption?
This is how I encrypt my link:

```
$cryptKey = 'qJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp';
$qEncoded = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($cryptKey),
                          $q,
                          MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
                          md5(md5($cryptKey))));
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Are you sure that it is not possible to include a '+' sign in a QR code ? Because if it is the problem is in the QR code creation step, not in the encoding step.

Answer (score 0):

From a [7-year-old comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php#103849) in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php):

For anyone interested in the 'base64url' variant encoding, you can use this pair of functions:

```
<?php
function base64url_encode($data) {
  return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '=');
}

function base64url_decode($data) {
  return base64_decode(str_pad(strtr($data, '-_', '+/'), strlen($data) % 4, '=', STR_PAD_RIGHT));
}
?>
```

- gutzmer at usa dot net

Answer (score 0):

You've misinterpreted the problem.

A `+` sign has special meaning in a URL. It is one way you can express a space.

If you want to include `+` as data in a URL then you need to encode it as `%2B`.

Answer (score 0):

`ASLV2N0+YmkHz6ELPjgEoqbA7qYQ69eoTReV9jSwEviaqJi8j54kQmpbaVK58LlFZmjhKG+X3uyPpZ6fC0/H2A==` appears to be the raw base64 code. You can't just inject random data into a URL, you need to [encode it properly](http://php.net/rawurlencode), e.g.:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/cp/form?' . rawurlencode($qEncoded);
```

I also suggest you double-check the URL format. You had a double slash (it shouldn't be an issue but feels like typo) and an unnamed GET parameter (which may or may not be correct).

Comment: yes the double slash is a typo and I found the answer, I used str replace "+" to "word" after encrypt and str replace "word" to "+" after decrypt, works well.

Comment: @RavenAlinsonorin I don't really get it. Do you mean you've eventually written a custom hack instead of using the standard built-in function?